# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.web.observation.HttpRequestsObservationFilter

Tags: java, spring

**SOLUTION BELOW**

Im currently writing Tests for my spring boot application and encountered a strange error.

Here is one of my tests:

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class AuthControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private AuthController authController;

    @Autowired
    public MockMvc mockMvc;

    private final Gson gson = new Gson();

    private final JwtUtils jwtUtils = new JwtUtils();

    private TestLoginResponse savedJwtResponse;

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        assertThat(authController).isNotNull();
    }

    @Nested
    public class AuthTests {

        @Test
        void loginTest() throws Exception {


            mockMvc.perform(post(URLMapping.AUTH + URLMapping.LOGIN)
                            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                            .content(TestCommonRequests.LOGIN_REQUEST))
                    .andDo(print(System.out))
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andDo(result -> {
                        String contentAsString = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
                        savedJwtResponse = gson.fromJson(contentAsString, TestLoginResponse.class);
                    })
                    .andExpect(result -> {
                        assertThat(savedJwtResponse).isNotNull();
                        assertThat(savedJwtResponse.getAccessToken()).isNotNull();
                        assertThat(savedJwtResponse.getRefreshToken()).isNotNull();
                        assertThat(savedJwtResponse.getEmail()).isNotNull();
                        assertThat(savedJwtResponse.getRole()).isEqualTo("ROLE_MANAGEMENT");
                    });
        }
    }
}
```

this worked perfectly fine yesterday but when i run them today they all failed with a similar exception:

```
class org.springframework.web.observation.HttpRequestsObservationDocumentation$LowCardinalityKeyNames tried to access private method 'void org.springframework.web.observation.HttpRequestsObservationDocumentation$LowCardinalityKeyNames$1.<init>(java.lang.String, int)' (org.springframework.web.observation.HttpRequestsObservationDocumentation$LowCardinalityKeyNames and org.springframework.web.observation.HttpRequestsObservationDocumentation$LowCardinalityKeyNames$1 are in unnamed module of loader 'app'), (Nest host resolution of org.springframework.web.observation.HttpRequestsObservationDocumentation$LowCardinalityKeyNames with host org/springframework/web/observation/HttpRequestsObservationDocumentation failed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/micrometer/observation/docs/ObservationDocumentation, Nest host resolution of org.springframework.web.observation.HttpRequestsObservationDocumentation$LowCardinalityKeyNames$1 with host org/springframework/web/observation/HttpRequestsObservationDocumentation failed: ja
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.springframework.web.observation.HttpRequestsObservationDocumentation$LowCardinalityKeyNames tried to access private method 'void org.springframework.web.observation.HttpRequestsObservationDocumentation$LowCardinalityKeyNames$1.<init>(java.lang.String, int)' (org.springframework.web.observation.HttpRequestsObservationDocumentation$LowCardinalityKeyNames and org.springframework.web.observation.HttpRequestsObservationDocumentation$LowCardinalityKeyNames$1 are in unnamed module of loader 'app'), (Nest host resolution of org.springframework.web.observation.HttpRequestsObservationDocumentation$LowCardinalityKeyNames with host org/springframework/web/observation/HttpRequestsObservationDocumentation failed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/micrometer/observation/docs/ObservationDocumentation, Nest host resolution of org.springframework.web.observation.HttpRequestsObservationDocumentation$LowCardinalityKeyNames$1 with host org/springframework/web/observation/HttpRequestsObservationDocumentation failed: ja
    at org.springframework.web.observation.HttpRequestsObservationDocumentation$LowCardinalityKeyNames.<clinit>(HttpRequestsObservationDocumentation.java:59)
    at org.springframework.web.observation.DefaultHttpRequestsObservationConvention.<clinit>(DefaultHttpRequestsObservationConvention.java:36)
    at org.springframework.web.observation.HttpRequestsObservationFilter.<clinit>(HttpRequestsObservationFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.extractMatchDetails(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.handleMatch(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:145)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.handleMatch(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:68)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:438)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:383)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:68)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:504)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector.doWithMatchingMapping(HandlerMappingIntrospector.java:173)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector.doWithMatchingMappingIgnoringException(HandlerMappingIntrospector.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector.getCorsConfiguration(HandlerMappingIntrospector.java:143)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:86)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:360)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:360)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilterInternal(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:360)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:360)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:360)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:224)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:351)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:201)
    at at.[redacted].AuthControllerTest$AuthTests.loginTest(AuthControllerTest.java:49)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:727)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:147)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:217)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:213)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:138)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy5.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:133)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:71)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
```

does anyone have an idea what the issue could be? Am I missing something?

I think it has something to do with `mockMvc.perform()`

**SOLUTION:**

It must have had something to do with the recent build of spring `3.0.0-SNAPSHOT`. After reverting to a more stable version everything worked fine again. (`3.0.0-M5`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue today, and a web search led me here.

I believe something got broken recently. I was using Spring Boot v. 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT, and reverting to 3.0.0-M5 solved the problem.

Comment: You are my hero. This worked for me.

Comment: yep this was the issue. I fixed it yesterday as well sorry for not letting you know.